# Finding maximum y value on a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, max

I have a large set of raw data that corresponds to load-displacement which I would like to plot. [Refer to a sample here: http://pastebin.com/qgZGs39K]

I want to store the displacement data in an array x and the load data in an array y, then plot(x,y) and finally find the maximum value for load on the curve.

If my understanding is correct, something like ymax=max(y) would return the maximum value in the array rather than the maximum value on the plot. Would the interp1 command be useful here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But the maximum value in the array is also the maximum value on the plot... I don't understand your question

Comment: Pastebin has been removed, and in general it is not clear what you are looking for. -- Untill you would add a clear example of input *and* output, I have voted to close this question as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. [Here](http://pastebin.com/kvxUND7m) is a reuploaded csv of the data and [this](http://imgur.com/a/08Dnb) diagram should clarify my query. Thanks for replying

Comment: Take the highest actual measured point, anything else involves making assumptions about your data

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure I got the question. As far as I understand, you have plotted data, and you want the maximum on the plot, which means that you want the maximum of the interpolated data, in other word, for points that are not part of the original x set.

If this is the question, there are few things to make clear. 
First, basing on my knowledge, plot command does not interpolate, it just links every point to the neighbouring. This means that the maximum of value in the array is exactly the maximum value on the plot.

A possibility would be using interp1, a command that I never met before. By looking on the guide, at link http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com, I understand that it gives you the chance to interpolate the set of data in points that are not the original ones. 
Hence, I think it should work. You just have to define an interpolating base (the x points where you don't know the y value in the original set) that is fine enough, so that you get the desired resolution.

Then you should go with the max command on the new vector. Be careful with the interp1, you must choose the proper interpolating method, because some of them (I think, for example, the linear one) should not find any new value for the y.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: "just links every point to the neighbouring" – a.k.a. piecewise linear _interpolation_

Comment: I knew it, you can deduce it when i wrote that the linear interpolation would not give any help. By interpolation I meant something that could be useful for the question. But you are right, I I used the words in an unproper manner. Sorry.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying to my question and sorry for not being clear. [Here](http://pastebin.com/kvxUND7m) is a reuploaded csv of the data and [this](http://imgur.com/a/08Dnb) diagram should help clarfiy